# getting "TypeError: undefined is not a function" when trying to open up the bottomsheet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

hey guys I have follow exactly what the demo page shows however i still getting this error when i try to open a bottom sheet. i'm using angularjs 1.3.14 and i have try on 1.3.6 as well.besides, i have follow the instruction on **Getting started** page to Including Angular Material and its dependencies.

**HTML(master.html this is the master page contain all the js and css library )**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.2/angular-material.min.css">
<div ng-controller="MasterCtrl">
<body>
<div class="bottom-sheet-demo inset" layout="column" layout-sm="row" layout-align="center">
    <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="showGridBottomSheet($event)">
      Show as Grid
    </md-button>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <b layout="row" layout-align="center center" layout-margin>
    {{alert}}
  </b>
  <div ng-view=""></div>
</body>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.2/angular-material.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascripts/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascripts/controllers.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngMaterial','ngRoute','ngSanitize','ngCookies','ngAnimate']).
 config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/static/views/main.html',
        controller: 'IndexCtrl'
      }).
      when('/signin',{
        templateUrl: '/static/views/signin.html',
        controller: 'SignInCtrl'
      }).
      when('/signup',{
        templateUrl: '/static/views/signup.html',
        controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        templateUrl: '/static/views/error.html'
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });

  }]);
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('app').controller('MasterCtrl', [
  '$http',
  '$scope',
  '$location',
  '$rootScope',
  '$timeout',
  '$mdBottomSheet',
  function ($http, $scope, $location, $rootScope, $timeout, $mdBottomSheet) {
      $scope.alert = '';
  $scope.showGridBottomSheet = function($event) {
    $scope.alert = '';
    $mdBottomSheet.show({
      templateUrl: 'bottom-sheet-grid-template.html',
      controller: 'GridBottomSheetCtrl',
      targetEvent: $event
    }).then(function(clickedItem) {
      $scope.alert = clickedItem.name + ' clicked!';
    });
  };
  }
]);
angular.module('app').controller('GridBottomSheetCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  '$mdBottomSheet',
  function ($scope,$mdBottomSheet) {
    $scope.items = [
    { name: 'Hangout', icon: 'hangout' },
    { name: 'Mail', icon: 'mail' },
    { name: 'Message', icon: 'message' },
    { name: 'Copy', icon: 'copy' },
    { name: 'Facebook', icon: 'facebook' },
    { name: 'Twitter', icon: 'twitter' },
  ];
  $scope.listItemClick = function($index) {
    var clickedItem = $scope.items[$index];
    $mdBottomSheet.hide(clickedItem);
  };
  }
]);
```

this is the error i get

[image]
[image]

I stuck here for few days i still can't able to figure it out i have tried to switch to non minified version of angular material to debug it however i have no luck and i don't get it why, can anyone of you teach me how to debug this kind of problem ? your help is appreciated thanks

Comment: Can you put your example to jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Any progress on this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on same issue.
I've temporarly resolved forcing `element[1]` instead of `element[0]`.
In some case `element[0]` is a text element and not a dom element.